# ruby on rails -- form table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

This is my table:

```
index.html.erb:



  <center><table border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="10" id="c"></center>
    <h3><center>List Of Products</h3></center>

    <tr>
    <th>S.No</th>
    <th>Products</th>
    <th>Availble Quantity</th>
    <th>Price(each per kg/qua)</th>
    <th>Quantity Requried<br>(enter required qua as per kg/qua)</br></th>
    </tr >
    <% @product.each do |product| %> 

    <tr>
    <td><center><%= product.id %></center></td>
    <td><center><%= check_box_tag "name" %> <%= product.name %></center></td>
    <td><center><%=product.quantity %></center></td>
    <td><center><%= product.price %></center></td>
    <td><center><input type= "text" style="width:50px;"></center></td>
    </tr>
    <% end %>  
    </table><br><br>
    <%= link_to "ADD",checkout_index_path, class: "btn btn-small btn-primary" %>
```

My question is, if I select any of the checkbox it should display the selected field in next page(i.e:index.html.erb/checkout)

my index.html.erb/checkout page:

```
 <p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>
    <h5>Slected products are:</h5>
    <%= link_to 'Continue Online Shopping', products_path %>
```

for example, if I select item 1 and click add button , it should display the selected item in checkout out page . Help me!!!!!

the selected items should display in this index.html.erb/checkout page

Comment: ...and what are you getting instead? error message? what's in params? etc?

Answer (score 0):

You have to put your table inside a Form. something like:

```
<%= form_tag :form_products, checkout_index_path do |f| %>
```

You should be defined as:
    <%= check_box_tag "name[#{product.id}]" %>

And then in your checkout action you will get all the parameters:
    params['name'][i] == '1'
where i is the producto id